# Have problem accesing data sent through jQuery $.post

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, python-requests

So I basically want to send information to my application (the table_name var) using the jQuery method $.post but when I try to access this data it appears as None in my console when I print it. Any help is appreciated.

**Javascript:**

```
function my_function(element_id) {

        console.log(element_id);
        var table_name = document.getElementById(element_id).textContent;
        console.log(table_name);
        $.post("/history", {table_name: table_name}, function(data) {

            document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = "<p> data </p>"

        });

    }
```

**Application.py:**

```
@app.route("/history", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def history():
if request.method == "POST":

    table_name = request.args.get("table_name")
    return table_name

else:

    user_history = "Graph"
    return render_template("history.html", user_history=user_history)
```

**Html:**

```
<button id="{{user_history}}" onclick="my_function(this.id)">stuff</button>
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Instead of ``return table_name``, wouldn't you need ``print(table_name)``?

Comment: @kmoser not really as I then want to do something through JS with that data (haven't gottet there yet). Is this not posible through $.post? Anyway, my error lies in sending and then accesing the data in my application.py.

Comment: @Twisty I Just did.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your data variable as plain text:

```
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = "<p> data </p>"
```

instead, try this:

```
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = "<p>" + data + "</p>"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the data I meant was the one I send through $.post (table_name: table_name}. This data is either not being sent properly or I Am unable to access it in my application.py.

Comment: got it. sending data looks good and should work fine. I think the problem is in retrieving this data, instead of request.args.get, try request.POST.get

Comment: I did with post as all caps and smallcase and got the following error: `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'POST'`

Answer (score 0):

I would make this a bit more jQuery and not mix Native JS and jQuery. Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function getData(tName, tObj) {
    $.post("/history", {
      table_name: tName
    }, function(data) {
      $("<td>").html("<p>" + data + "</p>").appendTo($("tr", tObj));
    });
  }

  $("button").on("click", function(e) {
    var i = $(this).attr("id");
    getData(i, $("#" + i + "-table"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="jsmith">Get Data</button>
<table id="jsmith-table">
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

HTML Table syntax has a specific structure that should be maintained.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `<tbody>` element can be skipped as there is no `<thead>` in this table. If the HTML Data you're sending back already has all this, you can drop it, but it did not seem that way with the `<p>` wrapping.

I'm assuming that `{{user_history}}` is populated with a id or name that is then used later to lookup the full details. So it would be best to have a function that can POST that detail via HTTP and then accept some data back into a Target jQuery Object. Since the `<button>` appears to have this written to it's ID attribute, hopefully this is unique, we can send that via POST.

Comment: `$("button").on("click` Would the previous line account for all buttons and activate when one is clicked?

Comment: BTW, my main problem is then accesing that data in my application.py and by some reason request doesn't seem to have the POST method in it. What request method should I use to then access the data sent through POST

Comment: @Omi11 yes, the jQuery selector would select all `<button>` elements and bind the call back to all of them. `$(this)` refers to the specific one that was clicked, the target of the event. I'm not familiar enough with Python to see where the is is there. I would suggest you review the web console for Network and see when you send to the script and what payload you get back.